# Can I do this extract code query in cakephp 3.5?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

My code in ServiceDetailController

```
  $users = $this->ServiceDetail->Users->find()->extract('first_name')->where(['position' => 2]);
```

I get an error:

> Call to undefined method Cake\ORM\ResultSet::where()

Answer (score 1):

Debugging basics: Check if the method exists in the called object. If not ask yourself why. Then check what extract() returns and you'll get your answer. You basic problem, as a metaphor is that you try to drink from a bottle before opening it. You can't extract without having a result first.

Extract does not return a query object. First build your query, then execute it, all() for example, and then call extract on the result object because it implements a collection that allows you to call extract() on it.

Comment: I think if you call `extract` on the query directly, without explicitly executing it via `all`, that will also work. The where condition definitely needs to be done first, though.